Effect of quantization on GLCM features
I have an image (float32) and I want to calculate the gray-level co-occurence matrix (GLCM) and derive features such as homogeneity and contrast from it.
In order to do that I need to discretize my original image to a fixed number of levels so that it has integer values. Currently I perform a simple uniform discretization.
However, when calculating the metrics from the GLCM, I don't see anything that adjusts for the total amount of levels or the way the discretization takes place. Meaning that discretizing an image to 64 or 256 levels results in different feature metrics. 
I hoped that a finer discretization would result in a more accurate representation of the GLCM metrics, but that is not the case since a finer discretization results in some features converging to zero...
Im breaking my head over this.. I must be misinterpreting something... so if anyone can make me sane again, that would be great!
PS: I already read the original paper by Haralicken and saw his equal-probability quantization function, but I think in that setting he already discretized his data...
EDIT:
To add some code and make it a bit more 'lively':
import os
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import graycomatrix, graycoprops
import skimage.util
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.data
import skimage.exposure


def get_quantization(img, glcm_metric='energy', n_start=256, n_stop=1024):
    metric_value = []
    for ii in range(n_start, n_stop):
        A_custom = (img * ii).astype(int)
        P = graycomatrix(
                    A_custom,
                    distances=[1],
                    angles=[0],
                    levels=ii+1,
                    symmetric=True,
                    normed=True,
                )
        z = graycoprops(P, glcm_metric)[0][0]
        metric_value.append(z)
    return metric_value

# Get an image
image = skimage.data.astronaut()[..., 0].astype(float)
# Add noise and make it a float
image += np.random.random(image.shape)
# Rescale to 0..1 for later conversion
image = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(image)
metric_value_quantization = get_quantization(image)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(256, 1024), metric_value_quantization, 'r')
plt.title('GLCM metric over different quantization levels')
ax.set_xlabel('number of bins')
ax.set_ylabel('GLCM metric value')

This results in the following graph. Here we see the monotic decrease of the GLCM feature as more bins are used. There are two interesting points but nevertheless, this graph shows to me the strange behavior of a decreasing GLCM value as we use more bins. Which just feels like a strange behavior for a metric. A logical result though from the mathematics behind it though! But Im curious if Im using the GLCM in a wrong way...


The GLCM strongly depends on the number of intensity levels. A finer discretization typically produces a sparser GLCM (this is particularly true for small images). Conversely, by reducing the number of intensity levels you can reasonably expect the GLCM to be denser. Try the following snippet to convince yourself:
import numpy as np
import skimage.data
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.feature import graycomatrix, graycoprops
from skimage.util import random_noise
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eps = 1e-6
levels = 2**np.arange(1, 9)
prop = 'energy'

rgb = skimage.data.astronaut()
gray = rgb2gray(rgb)
image = random_noise(gray, mode='gaussian', clip=True)

fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots(2, len(levels), figsize=(16, 4))
feature_values = []
for index, n_levels in enumerate(levels):
    bins = np.linspace(0, 1, n_levels+1)
    bins[-1] += eps
    quantized = np.digitize(image, bins=bins) - 1
    glcm = graycomatrix(
        quantized,
        distances=[1],
        angles=[0],
        levels=n_levels,
        symmetric=True,
        normed=True,
    )
    feature_values.append(graycoprops(glcm, prop=prop)[0][0])
    ax0[0, index].imshow(quantized, cmap='gray')
    ax0[0, index].set_title(f'{n_levels=}')
    ax0[1, index].imshow(np.squeeze(glcm))
fig0.suptitle('Gray level co-occurrence matrices')
fig0.tight_layout()


In a highly sparse GLCM most elements are 0 and as a consequence the energy takes a low value.
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(levels, feature_values, 'ro-')
ax1.set_title(f'{prop.capitalize()} vs. quantization levels')
ax1.set_xlabel('Number of bins')
ax1.set_ylabel(prop.capitalize())



Sorry I dont understand how this adds to the analysis that is already present in the post

The discretization has an impact on the sparsity of GLCM, which in turn influences the feature values. Consequently, if Haralick features are to be used in image classification, it is essential to select an appropriate number of intensity levels and discretise all images in the same way.

yes I understand that. I address exactly that behavior in my post and question whether this is a desirable property for a metric.
